# Including optional class in same function on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

so basically I have this script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("click", ".submenu-ctn .submenu-who nav a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('data-url') + ' #' + $(this).attr('data-target');
    $('.tile-area-main').load(url);
  });
});
```

and this corresponding snippet of the html so you can see the hierarchy...

```
<header class='masthead'>
  <div class='brand-container'>
    <a class='slide' href='#' data-url='who-are-musability-music-therapy.html' data-target='overview'>
      <span class='brand-initials'>Who Are Musability?</span>
      <span><i class="fa fa-briefcase brand-initials-icon"></i></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <div class='nav-container'>
      <div>
        <a class='slide' href='#' data-url='who-are-musability-music-therapy.html' data-target='mission'>
          <span class='element'>Mission and Values</span>
        </a>
      </div>
```

I basically want to also include the a href that is built into the header in the same function...

currently the function only looks at everything after nav.  How can I include all classes in this instance?

Comment: why not just apply to all a tags with `slide` as class? like this `$("body").on("click",".slide", ... );`

Comment: sounds too good to be true , would you leave it there and not put anything after .slide ?

Comment: will all the a tags that have this functionality (of loading) have `slide` as class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead select all a tags with slide as class. Like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").on("click", ".slide", function(e){ <------- .slide
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('data-url') + ' #' + $(this).attr('data-target');
    $('.tile-area-main').load(url);
  });
});
```